# Wildfly 10 - Migration From JBOSS 7.1.1 Final to Wildfly - resteasy

Tags: java, maven, jboss, resteasy, wildfly-10

I've got a problem when I tried to migrate a business application from Jboss 7.

I got this stacktrace :

```
    247341 [ServerService Thread Pool -- 5] ERROR org.jboss.msc.service.fail  - MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./starnet
org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./starnet: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'JSONReferentielGeolocBenefRessource' defined in "/D:/CloudStation/Slim/CloudStation/004_Developpement/star/Workspace/starnet-bom/starnet-web/target/starnet-web-6.0.4-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/net/star/starnet/web/rest/auth/ressources/json/JSONReferentielGeolocBenefRessource.class": Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.InjectorFactory.createPropertyInjector(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/jboss/resteasy/spi/PropertyInjector;
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'JSONReferentielGeolocBenefRessource' defined in "/D:/CloudStation/Slim/CloudStation/004_Developpement/star/Workspace/starnet-bom/starnet-web/target/starnet-web-6.0.4-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/net/star/starnet/web/rest/auth/ressources/json/JSONReferentielGeolocBenefRessource.class": Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.InjectorFactory.createPropertyInjector(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/jboss/resteasy/spi/PropertyInjector;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:250)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:546)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:517)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:559)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:101)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.InjectorFactory.createPropertyInjector(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/jboss/resteasy/spi/PropertyInjector;
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringBeanProcessor$ResteasyBeanPostProcessor.getInjector(SpringBeanProcessor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringBeanProcessor$ResteasyBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(SpringBeanProcessor.java:125)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1426)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    ... 37 more

247349 [management-handler-thread - 2] ERROR org.jboss.as.server  - WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "starnet-web-6.0.4-SNAPSHOT.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./starnet" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./starnet: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'JSONReferentielGeolocBenefRessource' defined in \"/D:/CloudStation/Slim/CloudStation/004_Developpement/star/Workspace/starnet-bom/starnet-web/target/starnet-web-6.0.4-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/net/star/starnet/web/rest/auth/ressources/json/JSONReferentielGeolocBenefRessource.class\": Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.InjectorFactory.createPropertyInjector(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/jboss/resteasy/spi/PropertyInjector;
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'JSONReferentielGeolocBenefRessource' defined in \"/D:/CloudStation/Slim/CloudStation/004_Developpement/star/Workspace/starnet-bom/starnet-web/target/starnet-web-6.0.4-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/net/star/starnet/web/rest/auth/ressources/json/JSONReferentielGeolocBenefRessource.class\": Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.InjectorFactory.createPropertyInjector(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/jboss/resteasy/spi/PropertyInjector;
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.InjectorFactory.createPropertyInjector(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/jboss/resteasy/spi/PropertyInjector;"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./starnet"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined
}

[2018-01-17 03:20:41,313] Artifact starnet-web:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2018-01-17 03:20:41,314] Artifact starnet-web:war exploded: java.lang.Exception: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./starnet" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./starnet: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'JSONReferentielGeolocBenefRessource' defined in \"/D:/CloudStation/Slim/CloudStation/004_Developpement/star/Workspace/starnet-bom/starnet-web/target/starnet-web-6.0.4-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/net/star/starnet/web/rest/auth/ressources/json/JSONReferentielGeolocBenefRessource.class\": Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.InjectorFactory.createPropertyInjector(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/jboss/resteasy/spi/PropertyInjector;
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'JSONReferentielGeolocBenefRessource' defined in \"/D:/CloudStation/Slim/CloudStation/004_Developpement/star/Workspace/starnet-bom/starnet-web/target/starnet-web-6.0.4-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/net/star/starnet/web/rest/auth/ressources/json/JSONReferentielGeolocBenefRessource.class\": Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.InjectorFactory.createPropertyInjector(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/jboss/resteasy/spi/PropertyInjector;
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.InjectorFactory.createPropertyInjector(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/jboss/resteasy/spi/PropertyInjector;"},"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./starnet"],"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined}
```

I already updated my pom.xml in order to match with the same version of resteasy on Wildfly

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.19.Final</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
            <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

And i also added a deployment descriptor in order to deactivate some module on Jboss and use the resteasy from Jboss as well.

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="webservices" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="javax.xml.ws.api" export="true" />
            <module name="javax.jws.api" export="true" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Do you have any ideas in order to resolve that problem ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked if the module exists or have you added it in wildfly? It might be that it isn't loaded because it doesn't exist or the versions have conflict.

Comment: Unfortunately, It exists.

Comment: I think you defined the name of the `Resteasy` module incorrectly. If you are planning to use the one provided by Wildfly then it should be something like `org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs`. The `Resteasy` modules are located in  Wildfly in `wildfly-10.1.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\org\jboss\resteasy`. So you should add this module `<module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs" export="true" />`.

Comment: What is the version of 'resteasy-spring' that you are using? It appears that it isn't  the correct one. Because resteasy-jaxrs {3.0.19.Final} has the method 'createPropertyInjector' with the parameters "(ResourceClass resourceClass, ResteasyProviderFactory providerFactory)" and the 'resteasy-spring' version is giving only the (Ljava/lang/Class;)